# Drupal 8, print the form and send the data to the database

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8, drupal-views

There is a page in the menu.

When you go to this page, you need to display the form.

The user fills in the form and the data is sent to the database.

How to implement it?

Comment: I don't see "page in the menu".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too vague. Do you mean **display** the form to be filled out? Or **print** the form to be downloaded? 
Drupal has a module called [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) which is a complete solution to this request, there are also many add-on modules to webform that really make this a powerhouse. Drupal has been doing forms for many years and Drupal 8 has an incredibly powerful, completely documented version of Webform to use.